# DFA for odd sequences of 1 and 0

Tags: sequence, dfa

I want to create a DFA for language {1,0} which accepts only words build from sequences of odd 1 and 0.
I've found many examples for DFA with even/odd numbers of 0 and 1 in a string but not in each sequence of that string. I cannot grasp how to create said graph. Should it be build with 4 states or maybe 3?

Just thought about something, is this one correct or am I mistaken here?
[image]

Ok, so this one was wrong, but maybe this one?
[image]
With this one, however, I fell like you always have to start with either one 1 or one 0 and won't get more in the first sequence so it's not relly perfect...

Kind regards,

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sequences of odd 1 and 0"? Each group of 1 or 0 within the word must have an odd lenght? Ie for instance 1000111 would be a valid word 100011 wouldn't?

Comment: exactly, 1000111, 1110111000, 01000111 would be valid ones

Comment: Hm, assuming the leftmost state is your starting state, your DFA would for instance accept 1101 which, if I understand correctly is wrong. And it won't accept any words starting with 01xxx or 10xxx

Comment: In your diagram, which is the starting state?  Is the state on the right accepting or rejecting?  Try stepping through some examples with it.

Comment: most left one is the starting one and most right one is the accepting one and yeah I just saw that this would be ok if it wasnt for sequences...

Comment: Are words like "111" or "000" valid, or does each of the symbols have to appear at least once (ie zero-occurence is not considered odd)

Comment: well this is not stated in exercise so I would assume that 111 or 000 would be valid ones unless it depends how one understands it: 'Give a deterministic finite automaton accepting those words over the alphabet {0, 1}, where each series of zeros and each series of 1s is of odd length.'

Comment: your second approach is not a deterministic FA (there are two possiblities for 0 when you are in the upper state) and it accepts for instance 10110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Give a deterministic finite automaton accepting those words over the alphabet {0, 1}, where each series of zeros and each series of 1s is of odd length.

Is not 100% unambiguous. I personally understand, that the empty word, and a word consisting solely of `0`s or solely of `1`s is also part of the language (if it is of odd length). Then something like the following should do the trick.

State `1` is the starting state. The "upper" branch (ie states 2, 3) is for accepting any odd number of `0`, the "lower" branch (ie states 4,5) accepts any odd number of `1`. You can "enter" the respective branch only by reading a single instance of the respective symbol, either starting from the empty word, or after reading an odd number of the respective other symbol.

[image]

For instance the word `1000111110001`. After reading a single `1` you are in state `4`. By reading a single `0`, you switch to the "upper branch" and now can read any even (in this case 2) number of `0`, which will always bring you back to the accepting state `2`. Reading a `1` in state `3` is not possible (because the word would be invalid). Reading a single `1` in state `2` brings you back to state `4`. And from here similar to the above, you can read any even number (in this case 4) of `1` which will always bring you back to the accepting state `4`. And so on and so forth. If the symbol changes (or the word ends) after an even number of equal symbols, you are either in state `3` or `5`, which are both not accepting, thus the word won't be accepted.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Also, for some reason I didn't know that you can have multiple states for ending words (will keep that in mind). I'm still learning about this and somehow must have missed this thing. Maybe the examples I was looking at made me think that. Anyway, thanks again for the help :)